# Error with Static Method: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void createNewTranslationProject(List<String>, String)

Tags: apex

I am running into the following error message:
`Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void createNewTranslationProject(List<String>, String)`

I am unable to debug this error and unsure of what I am missing.

Trigger Handler Class

```
public static void uploadSurveyDataToOHT(List<SurveyTranslation__e> ev){
        //string to hold all encoded data
        List<String> encodedSurveyData = new List<String>();
        String languageSelection;
        //string to hold all language values
        try{
            //loops throught all Survey Events
            for (SurveyTranslation__e e : ev) {
                //encodes all survey fields and adds them to the ev list 
                encodedSurveyData.add(EncodingUtil.urlEncode(e.SurveyLabel__c, 'UTF-8'));
                encodedSurveyData.add(EncodingUtil.urlEncode(e.SurveyVersionLabel__c, 'UTF-8'));
                encodedSurveyData.add(EncodingUtil.urlEncode(e.SurveyLabel__c, 'UTF-8'));
                encodedSurveyData.add(EncodingUtil.urlEncode(e.SurveyQuestionData__c, 'UTF-8'));
                languageSelection = e.SurveyLanguage__c;
            }
            //will need to change the translated status value
            System.debug(encodedSurveyData);
            System.debug(languageSelection);
            //call the oht api class
            Integer projectId = TranslationAPI.createNewTranslationProject(encodedSurveyData, languageSelection);
            System.debug(projectId);

        } catch (Exception e){
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            System.debug('the handler ran');
        }
    }
```

Static Method Being Called:

```
public static Integer createNewTranslationProject(String encodedSurveyData, String languageSelection){
    //call the resource method and get it back as a string
    String textResourcePlayload = String.valueOf(uploadTextResource(encodedSurveyData));
    //replaces the perens from the json payload
    String resources = textResourcePlayload.substring(1, textResourcePlayload.length()-1);
    System.debug('this is the string' + resources);
    //create HTTP Object and init setup
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    //sets the endpoint ... this is in sandbox mode
    request.setEndpoint('/api/' + resources + '&source_language=en-us&target_language=' + languageSelection);
    
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    //basic error handleing
    try {
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        //gets the body
        Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
        //gets the result array
        Map<String,Object> status = (Map<String,Object>) data.get('results');
        //gets the project id
        Integer projectId = (Integer) status.get('project_id');
        System.debug(status);
        System.debug(projectId);
        return projectId;

        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug(e);
        return 0;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your types are incorrect.

```
public static Integer createNewTranslationProject(String encodedSurveyData, String languageSelection){
```

This method takes two `String` parameters.

But this call has a `List<String>`, as I've called out below

```
Integer projectId = TranslationAPI.createNewTranslationProject(
    List<String> encodedSurveyData,
    String languageSelection
);
```

You'll certainly have to change one or the other, although I'm not clear enough on exactly what your code is doing to recommend exactly how (`uploadTextResource()` is not given here).

Comment: Wow, I can not believe I missed that. Thank you!